# python xlrd unsupported format, or corrupt file.

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

My code:

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("Z:\\Data\\Locates\\3.8 locates.xls")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
print sh.cell(0,0).value
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Z:\Wilson\tradedStockStatus.py", line 18, in <module>
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("Z:\\Data\\Locates\\3.8 locates.xls")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 429, in open_workbook
biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1545, in getbof
bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1539, in bof_error
raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;
found '<table r'"
```

The file doesn't seem to be corrupted or of a different format. 
Anything to help find the source of the issue would be great.

Comment: 1. Try changing the file name (lose the numbers and spaces at the beginning) 2. Is the file password protected?

Comment: I tried changing the file name with the same result and the file is not password protected.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You say:

> The file doesn't seem to be corrupted or of a different format.

However as the error message says, the first 8 bytes of the file are `'<table r'` ... that is definitely not Excel `.xls` format. Open it with a text editor (e.g. Notepad) that won't take any notice of the (incorrect) `.xls` extension and see for yourself.

Comment: By the same token, if I get (and I am getting) a similar error but with *XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '<?xml ve'*, this would imply that my *xls* is really an *xlsx*?

Comment: @Pyderman no it's not an xlsx file. Could have been saved as XML Spreadsheet (*.xml) (not supported by xlrd)

Comment: thanks - i changed my file from .csv to .xls and my code worked.

Answer (score 67):

Try to open it as an HTML with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_html('filename.xls')
```

Or try any other html python parser.

That's not a proper excel file, but an html readable with excel.

Comment: Hi, open your xls with text editor and see if it is html. If you get the error in the first top it is an html. I don't see then why if you try to use read_html you get a "no tables found".

Comment: This is the solution for me! Thanks!

Comment: I saved it from microsoft365 in my browser as .xlsx, but yea, starts with <!DOCTYPE html> so, thank you :)

Answer (score 16):

This will happen to some files while also open in Excel.

Comment: I got this error message and it was indeed because I had the file opened whilst running the code. Thanks.

Comment: Yes，you're right！In my case, the file extension is xls, but the content in thefile is actually HTML...

Comment: This was my issue as well

Comment: This was exactly my issue! Another reminder of why I try to stick to plain CSV, or ODS in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and it was related to the version. In a python terminal check:

```
>> import xlrd
>> xlrd.__VERSION__
```

If you have **'0.9.0'** you can open almost all files. If you have **'0.6.0'** which was what I found on Ubuntu, you may have problems with newest Excel files. You can download the latest version of xlrd using the Distutils standard.

Comment: "may have problems" is inaccurate. xlrd 0.6.0 doesn't handle xlsx files at all. 0.6.0 is an unsupported antique.

Answer (score 6):

I found the similar problem when downloading .xls file and opened it using xlrd library. Then I tried out the solution of converting .xls into .xlsx as detailed here: [how to convert xls to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx)

It works like a charm and rather than opening .xls, I am working with .xlsx file now using openpyxl library.

Hope it helps to solve your issue.

Comment: sorry, it couldn't help, because error 'xlrd.open_workbook' and any convertor couldn't help until there is error

Answer (score 5):

I had faced the same `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;` error and solved it by writing an XML to XLSX converter. The reason is that actually, xlrd does not support XML Spreadsheet (*.xml) i.e. NOT in XLS or XLSX format.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def convert_to_xlsx():
    with open('sample.xls') as xml_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file.read(), 'xml')
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx')
        for sheet in soup.findAll('Worksheet'):
            sheet_as_list = []
            for row in sheet.findAll('Row'):
                sheet_as_list.append([cell.Data.text if cell.Data else '' for cell in row.findAll('Cell')])
            pd.DataFrame(sheet_as_list).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet.attrs['ss:Name'], index=False, header=False)

        writer.save()
```

Comment: This just gave a blank .xlsx file

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the same problem (the output is blank file)

Answer (score 5):

It may be an old excel file format. It can be read as html in pandas via

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('file.xls')
```

Eventually, this gives a list of dataframes (if you check the type is a list). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/io.html#io-read-html

You need to extract them, for instance with `df[0]`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, after opening the file with a text editor as @john-machin suggested, I realized the file is not encrypted as an Excel file is supposed to but it's in the CSV format and was saved as an Excel file. What I did was renamed the file and its extension and used `read_csv` function instead:

```
os.rename('sample_file.xls', 'sample_file.csv')
csv = pd.read_csv("sample_file.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Yes! I got the same error when I saved the file using to_csv() but passed ".xlsx" as the file format(mistakes yk).

Answer (score 3):

Try this It worked for me.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('filename.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too.I opened this file by excel and saved it as other formats such as excel 97-2003 and finally I solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Those old files are formatted like a tab-delimited file. I've been able to open my problem files with `read_table`; ie `df = pd.read_table('trouble_maker.xls')`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried to read some XLSX files from a folder and that one of the files was opened. I closed the XLSX file and this error did not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded xlrd, created an excel document (excel 2007) for testing and got the same error (message says 'found PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00'). Extension is a xlsx. Tried saving it to an older .xls format and error disappears .....

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem.

it lies in the .xls file itself - it looks like an Excel file however it isn't. (see if there's a pop up when you plainly open the .xls from Excel)

sjmachin commented on Jan 19, 2013 from https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/26 helps.

Answer (score 0):

Worked on the same issue , finally done this is top for the question so just putting what i did.

Observation - 
1 -The file was not actually XLS i renamed to txt and noticed HTML text in file.

2 - Renamed the file to html and tried reading pd.read_html, Failed.

3- Added  as it was not there in txt file, removed style to ensure that table is displaying in browser from local, and WORKED.

Below is the code may help someone..

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
import html5lib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

shutil.copy('your.xls','file.html')
shutil.copy('file.html','file.txt')
time.sleep(2)

txt = open('file.txt','r').read()

# Modify the text to ensure the data display in html page, delete style

txt = str(txt).replace('<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </script>','')

# Add head and body if it is not there in HTML text

txt_with_head = '<html><head></head><body>'+txt+'</body></html>'

# Save the file as HTML

html_file = open('output.html','w')
html_file.write(txt_with_head)

# Use beautiful soup to read

url = r"C:\Users\hitesh kumar\PycharmProjects\OEM ML\output.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="lxml")
my_table = soup.find("table",attrs={'border': '1'})

frame = pd.read_html(str(my_table))[0]
print(frame.head())
frame.to_excel('testoutput.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open in google sheets and then download from sheets as CSV and then reupload to drive. Then you can Open CSV file from python.

Comment: can you add some reference links

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I know of is to just download the xls file once again and if you are doing in google colab, just load the file once again from your computer and run the pd.read_excel("filename,xlsx") once again . It should work.

Answer (score 0):

As they already wrote it is actually html, to see the first table you can use

```
df= pd.read_html(file)
df[0]
```

To see how many tables there are you can use

```
print('Tables found:', len(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, using `encoding="utf-8"` from this post
[UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 100: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561407/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x90-in-position-100-char)

```
    def convert_to_xlsx():
        with open('sample.xls', encoding="utf-8") as xml_file:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file.read(), 'xml')
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx')
            for sheet in soup.findAll('Worksheet'):
                sheet_as_list = []
                for row in sheet.findAll('Row'):
                    sheet_as_list.append([cell.Data.text if cell.Data else '' for cell in row.findAll('Cell')])
                pd.DataFrame(sheet_as_list).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet.attrs['ss:Name'], index=False,
                                                     header=False)

            writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

melike's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63016833/18610547) works for me, while the last output sentence did't work, so if anyone has the same issue with me and wants to output the xlsx file into local location, can just easily modify the last three lines.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def convert_to_xlsx():
    with open('sample.xls') as xml_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file.read(), 'xml')
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx')
        for sheet in soup.findAll('Worksheet'):
            sheet_as_list = []
            for row in sheet.findAll('Row'):
                sheet_as_list.append([cell.Data.text if cell.Data else '' for cell in row.findAll('Cell')]) 
        output_df = pd.DateFrame(sheet_as_list)
        output_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1',index=False, header=False)
        writer.close()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33477840)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Rename the file if it's not already a .csv file
if not os.path.exists('3.8 locates.csv'):
    os.rename('3.8 locates.xls', '3.8 locates.csv')

# Load the data into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("3.8 locates.csv", sep='\t|\n', engine='python')

# Show the first 5 rows of the dataframe
print(df.head())
```

The code imports the os and pandas modules and then uses them to perform the following operations:

1. Check if the file '3.8 locates.csv' exists.
2. If it does not exist, it renames the file '3.8 locates.xls' to '3.8 locates.csv'.
3. Load the contents of the file '3.8 locates.csv' into a Pandas dataframe using the pd.read_csv method. The sep argument is set to '\t|\n' and the engine argument is set to 'python' to handle the file's separators correctly.
4. Print the first 5 rows of the dataframe using the df.head() method.
   Note: The code may not work as expected if the file is not a valid tab-separated or newline-separated file.

Answer (score -1):

there's nothing wrong with your file. xlrd does not yet support xlsx (excel 2007+) files although it's purported to have supported this for some time.

[Simplistix github](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/commit/5ee3e133e4db8780267e9e685f691fa3373655c5)

2-days ago they committed a pre-alpha version to their git which integrates xlsx support. Other forums suggest that you use a DOM parser for xlsx files since the xlsx file type is just a zip archive containing XML. I have not tried this. there is another package with similar functionality as xlrd and this is called openpyxl which you can get from easy_install or pip. I have not tried this either, however, its API is supposed to be similar to xlrd.

Comment: -1 (1) His file starts with `'<table r'`. It is NOT an XLSX file; a ZIP archive starts with `'PK'` (2) "other forums" suggest things that they have not tried or work only on tiny files and/only on their own simplistic application (3) `openpyxl` is a port of a PHP package and its API could only be supposed to be similar to xlrd by someone who was guessing wildly.

Comment: thank you for xlrd and building support for xlsx, John! xlrd is IMHO the best python module for handling excel files. If i can help support your work monetarily, or otherwise, please let me know how...

Answer (score -1):

I know there should be a proper way to solve it
but just to save time

I uploaded my xlsx sheet to Google Sheets and then again downloaded it from Google Sheets
it working now

If you don't have time to solve the problem, you can try this

Comment: Please review the answers already given to this question before adding a new one, especially if there is already an accepted solution.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes help to add `?raw=true` at the end of a file path. For example:

```py
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("Z:\\Data\\Locates\\3.8 locates.xls?raw=true")
```