# xlrd reading xls XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\r\n<html>'

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xls, xlrd

This is the code:

```
xls = open_workbook('data.xls')
```

In return:

```
File "/home/woles/P2/fin/fin/apps/data_container/importer.py", line 16, in import_data
  xls = open_workbook('data.xlsx')
File "/home/woles/P2/fin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 435,     in open_workbook
ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "/home/woles/P2/fin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
File "/home/woles/P2/fin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1230, in getbof
bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
File "/home/woles/P2/fin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1224, in bof_error
raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\r\n<html>'
```

The file is not damaged, I can open it with Excel, LibreOffice.

Comment: See [python xlrd unsupported format, or corrupt file.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15437095/222914)

Comment: The file isn't necessarily *damaged* but it's not *supported*. Excel can open lots of things that are not supported by `xlrd`, such as CSV, SYLK, DIF, and many others. The fact that the error message tells you what it *did* find is a clue to what kind of file it **really** is. It's definitely not a real XLSX file, just named like one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_html(filename.xls)
```

Or try any other html python parser.

That's not a proper excel file, but an html readable with excel.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error resolved just now, first step id check changing the file to text and notice html content , than did some modification to ensure that once I save it as HTML and open in browser than table should be visible. Than Beautiful Soup and pandas helped me to get excel output....

check below lines if may help..

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
import html5lib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

shutil.copy('donloaded.xls','changed.html')
shutil.copy('changed.html','txt_output.txt')
time.sleep(2)

txt = open('txt_output.txt','r').read()

# Modify the text to ensure the data display in html page

txt = str(txt).replace('<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </script>','')

# Add head and body if it is not there in HTML text

txt_with_head = '<html><head></head><body>'+txt+'</body></html>'

# Save the file as HTML

html_file = open('output.html','w')
html_file.write(txt_with_head)

# Use beautiful soup to read

url = r"C:\Users\hitesh kumar\PycharmProjects\OEM ML\output.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="lxml")
my_table = soup.find("table",attrs={'border': '1'})

frame = pd.read_html(str(my_table))[0]
print(frame.head())
frame.to_excel('testoutput.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `.xls` files you can use [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.read_excel("filename.xls")
```

The parameters `header` and `sep` may help you get rid of some errors ([here you can find more info on the parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)). An example of its usage

```
df2= pd.read_excel("filename.xls",  header = None, sep='delimiter')
```

**Note** that if the files are a `.csv` you will get the error

> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;

To read `.csv` one needs to use [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), like this

```
df3= pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```