# Reading a .xls file using pandas read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a `.xls` file that I have no trouble opening in Excel. Unfortunately, when trying to call the following function from the pandas module:

```
survey = pd.read_excel('ISU_Anketa_Ishodnie.xls', skiprows=1)
```

I receive the following error:

> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b''<'?xml ve'

I have tried saving that file in `.csv` format, but the only option Excel provides for delimiter is a comma, which is a problem as the data itself includes a lot of commas.

Comment: Maybe this can help you with your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994362/xlrd-reading-xls-xlrderror-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-re

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python xlrd unsupported format, or corrupt file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623029/python-xlrd-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file)

Comment: try to write survey = pd.read_html("ISU_Anketa_Ishodnie.xls", skiprows=1)

Comment: can you share us an example about your file ?