# Trouble with updating lists and dictionaries in a for loop

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import bs4
import datetime
import time

#options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.rankonesport.com/Calendar/?D=e8bb5c10-8d0c-4b26-
b304-262397124de8")

weekly = driver.find_element_by_id("cmd_Weekly").click()

source = driver.page_source

bs_source = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

month = datetime.date.today().month

year_end = 5
total = 12
times = 0

if month <= year_end:
    times = year_end - month

if month == year_end:
    times = 1

if month >= year_end:
    value = month - year_end

    times = total - value

times *= 5

mylist = []
#{EventName:[Date, Where, Time(Start), Time(End)]}
mydict = {}

for x in range(times):


    events = bs_source.find('table', id='gv_Events')


    for tr in events.find_all('tr', class_='lightgray'):

        td = tr.find_all('td')
        mylist.append(td)

    for tr2 in events.find_all('tr', class_='white'):

        td2 = tr2.find_all('td')
        mylist.append(td2)

    next = driver.find_element_by_id('lnk_Next_Day').click()


for event in mylist:
    mydict.update({event[0].text: [event[2].text, event[1].text, 
    event[3].text, event[4].text]})

print(mylist)
print(mydict)
```

So my school has an online calendar that I am trying to scrape off of. My goal is to pull each event, that happens before the school year ends, and their corresponding properties such as time and date.

I have the script loop through the calendar portion that has the events by week and pull them off. The calendar is a JS based calendar so the link does not change when the script goes and clicks the next button. I store the events and their properties in a list and then throw them into a dictionary in order to easily access them by name.

What I want to happen is the dictionary to be full of as many events as the script loops through. Rather the dictionary only contains a select few which seem to be the first couple of events it parses through. The events have the same HTML ids and classes when the next page is pulled up so it should just rinse and repeat the code as many times as I have it.

If someone could point something out that I missed or lead me in the right direction that would be awesome as I have spent way to much time trying to figure this out myself.

Links:

[Calendar](https://www.rankonesport.com/Calendar/Daily.aspx?S=&D=e8bb5c10-8d0c-4b26-b304-262397124de8&Date=2/28/2018)
[Calendar Outline](http://prntscr.com/il7hin)

Dictionary Output:

```
{'Sadie Ticket Sales': ['3/1/2018', 'New Cafeteria, 541 Chartres St. LaSalle, Lasalle, IL 61301', '11:00 AM', '1:00 PM'], 
 'Winter Guard Practice': ['3/3/2018', ' East Gym, 541 Chartres St. LaSalle, Lasalle, IL 61301', '5:00 PM', '8:00 PM'], 
 'Sadie Dance': ['3/3/2018', 'Sellett Gym, 541 Chartres St. LaSalle, Lasalle, IL 61301', '8:00 PM', '11:00 PM']}
```

^Should be way, way more events

List output:

```
[[<td>Sadie Ticket Sales</td>, <td>New Cafeteria, 541 Chartres St. LaSalle, Lasalle, IL 61301</td>, <td>2/26/2018</td>, <td>11:00 AM</td>, <td>1:00 PM</td>, <td>Non-Game Activity</td>, <td align="center"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('gv_Events','Outlook$0')">Sync</a></td>],
 [<td>Winter Guard Practice</td>, <td>North Balcony, 541 Chartres St. LaSalle, Lasalle, IL 61301</td>, <td>2/27/2018</td>, <td>6:30 PM</td>, <td>9:00 PM</td>, <td>Non-Game Activity</td>, <td align="center"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('gv_Events','Outlook$2')">Sync</a></td>],
 ...]
```

It seems to repeat those events over and over in the list ^

Thanks.

Edit 1:

```
mylist = []
#{EventName:[Date, Where, Time(Start), Time(End)]}
mydict = {}

for x in range(5):

    source = driver.page_source

    bs_source = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    events = bs_source.find('table', id='gv_Events')


    for tr in events.find_all('tr', class_='lightgray'):

        td = tr.find_all('td')
        mylist.append(td)

    for tr2 in events.find_all('tr', class_='white'):

        td2 = tr2.find_all('td')
        mylist.append(td2)

    next = driver.find_element_by_id('lnk_Next_Day').click()


for event in mylist:
    mydict.update({event[0].text: [event[2].text, event[1].text, 
    event[3].text, event[4].text]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing the html, what about downloading the excel files? This seems to download all of the events you are after.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.rankonesport.com/Calendar/?D=e8bb5c10-8d0c-4b26-b304-262397124de8"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

weekly = driver.find_element_by_id("cmd_Weekly")
weekly.click()

while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cmd_Export_Event_Excel"))
        ).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.quit()
        break
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_id('lnk_Next_Day').click()
```

Then, using `pandas` and some help from stackoverflow, you can write the results out to a csv file.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512931/8079103
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725123/8079103

---

```
import os
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd

dfs = []
dir_path = '/home/lettuce/Downloads'
for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if f.endswith('.xls'):
        df = pd.read_html('{}/{}'.format(dir_path, f))[0]
        dfs.append(df)

df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, how='outer'), dfs)
df_final.to_csv('all_events.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

[Link to the csv output file](https://bpaste.net/show/8cd335241716)

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of that. It looks way more efficient as well.

Comment: @SamScolari No problem, I had to learn a couple things to get this to work so it was a good exercise!

Answer (score 0):

You only ever fetch the contents of the page once, at the beginning of your script:

```py
source = driver.page_source

bs_source = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
```

As you navigate the calendar by clicking "Next", `bs_source` will continue to contain the source for the first page, meaning you will forever be re-processing the first page.

The simplest fix is to instantiate `bs_source` at the start of your loop, before you look for any elements.

Comment: Adding bs_scource to the loop does not change anything in the output. I'm going to go with Delirious's answer. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I have since moved on writing it to a .csv file. If you are still interested, the edit 1 in my question above is the code I had before I decided to go the other route.