# not able to open .xlsx in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, excel-2016, xlrd

I have a "2016 excel file" `Sb_test.xlsx` which I want to convert to `.csv` file. However,

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<## NASC'
```

occured at line 
`wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r"D:/Sb_test.xlsx")` of the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import os, xlrd, csv

def csv_from_excel():
    print (xlrd.__VERSION__, xlrd.__file__) # suggested at google forum
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r"D:/Sb_test.xlsx")
    print (xlrd.__VERSION__, xlrd.__file__)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Basic_Classification')
    your_csv_file = open('Sb_01_csv.csv', 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()

csv_from_excel()
```

Looking for a solution I found out that I might be using the older version of `xlrd`, but no, it is **1.2.0** (the most recent one)

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623029/python-xlrd-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file) an accepted answer suggests opening it using a text editor, which in my case looks like this:

[image]

Once I realized that

> ... that is definitely not Excel .xls format

what am I supposed to do know to convert the (whatever type) file to csv format?

All I want is to have a CSV type file to further try some machine learning stuff.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the file encrypted?

Comment: @user2263572, since its initial bytes start as `NASCA ..` , yes. And is it because jupyter notebook uses a server and I have an encrypted file which is not allowed to be accessed ?

Comment: Can you just open with excel (enter the password) and save as filetype -> .csv?  Then use the python csv module to read in the file?

Comment: @user2263572 I did as you said, after some `UnicodeDecodeError` and `ParserError` errors occured, I end up using `encoding = "latin-1", sep='\t', header=None`. But when I try to print the `pd.head()` its output isn't readable. Any more ideas?

Comment: Did you save as csv or tsv in excel?  Also, post the code along with error messages.  You should also be able to open the csv file in a text editor to see if it looks correct.

Comment: @user2263572, yes I saved it as csv file, I solved all the above mentioned errors (UnicodeDecodeError and ParserError), I had tried opening with notepad++ and notepad, the former outputting unreadable content (`<## NASCA DRM`) and the latter outputting the content as it is.