# error> cannot import name 'load_workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do 'pd.read excel' but one file can be opened but newly imported file from other folder can not be opened with error like below. For reference, same format of excel file (xls)

Error message: xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xff\xfe\r\x00\n\x00\t\x00'

when I import openpyxl, error is like right below

Error message: ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl'

For reference, openpyxl version 3.0.4

Comment: Looks like wrong version of excel. Save the excel file as `xlsx` and retry.

Comment: I tried but it was not working..

Comment: Possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623029/python-xlrd-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file