# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 100: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, xml, python-unicode, wordnet

I have two files both at the same directory:

1. http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/AWNDatabaseManagement.py.gz
2. the xml database of Arabic WordNet (http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/get_bd.php) upc_db.xml

When i try to run the .py file to give me the error in the image
i am trying to check the .py file is working so i can import it as WordNet for arabic words

Can you help me through it?

Thanks

[image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUnYN.png)

Comment: Please do not post errors or code or both as images. Include these in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Still, perhaps you should use a different encoding such as UTF-8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Comment: Also, please search for the error message online. This one is trivial to find! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Without a [mcve], your question is considered off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 7):

To read any binary file/db use the `encoding="utf-8"` while opening the file/db.
UTF-8 is capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid character code points in Unicode using one to four one-byte code units.
So, simple is the best.

Comment: `encoding="uft-8"` => `encoding="utf-8"`

Answer (score 5):

To read the above binary file, use

```py
ent = open(ent, 'rb')
```

instead of,

```py
ent = open(ent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding it.

```py
with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    # Reads each character
    file.read()
```