# Is there a way to automate the reading of a corrupted xls file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database, dataframe

I'm at a project where I need to download from a bank's webpage an excel sheet. When dowloaded and opened in excel it appears a sign warning the file is corrupted. I accept and it works perfectly. Nevertheless, when trying to read it on python

```
df = pd.read_excel("path/name.xls")
```

an error pops up.

> Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record

I've tried with different encodings such as:

```
df=pd.read_excel("path/name.xls",encoding='utf-16le')
```

but it still does not work.

I've tried also reading with read_table :

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

These are the first rows of the dataset. The following rows, have the same format as the last ones.

[Screenshot of the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHIWh.png)

I'm quite new at python, and cannot manage to find the solution to this.
Would help any assistance.
Thanks

Comment: An XLS file is a binary file.  You can't use an encoding, and you obviously can't use `.readlines`..  You must use `file1 = io.open(filename, 'rb')`.

Comment: Did you try answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623029/python-xlrd-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file

Eg pd.read_html if the file is actually html

You should post first lines of the raw file if it opens in text editor

I got that by googling your error string,  come on people!

Comment: @spioter yes. I've tried. No progress made at all